# Fragment UI not visible while moving from one fragment to another fragment

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I m trying to move from existing fragment to another fragment.Transaction is successfully done but no ui element is visible.

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/mainLinearLayout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
tools:context=".Main.Main"></LinearLayout>
```

To jump to second fragment onclick -

```
case R.id.homeElectronicsLinearLayout:
            Fragment fragmentElectronics = new Electronicss();
            if(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()!=null){
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainLinearLayout,fragmentElectronics).hide(Main.this).addToBackStack(null).commit();

            }
            break;
```

Second Fragment -

```
public class Electronicss extends Fragment{

private RecyclerView twentyFourHoursDealsRecyclerView,justLaunchedRecyclerView,bestOfElectronicsRecyclerView;
private String featuredCategoryKey="featured";

public Electronicss() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_electronicss, container, false);

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return view;
}}
```

Second Fragment ui only contains a button but still it is not visible :-

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
tools:context=".Categories.Electronics.Electronicss">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button11"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Instead of adding fragment you can try replacing it.
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainLinearLayout,fragmentElectronics).addToBackStack(null).commit();

Comment: I got that.But after doing so no transaction is happening.

Comment: Please attach whole source code of host activity.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding fragment use replace,also change your LinearLayout to FrameLayout that acts as a container for fragment to be replaced.

Note: if you don't want fragment to be stored in a stack simply remove the line addToBackStack().

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, yourfragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
```

Comment: It's done but my new fragment overlaps over the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding fragment you can try replacing it.

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainLinearLayout,fragmentElectronics).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

As @Jiten Basnet said, you should also consider using FrameLayout instead of LinearLayout as container for your fragments.

Comment: Yes i replace 'add' with 'replace' but doing so don't put any effect instead no transaction is happening now,

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the answer.That i need to use frame layout as container for fragment and also need to set background and focusable n clickable = true in second fragment